# How to add custom animation in my flutter app homepage?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i put this code in my Flutter App Homepage ?
i want this animation to run at the beginning of my app when the app starts.I am a super beginner.

```
class _ScaleTransitionState extends State<ScaleTransition>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    AnimationController _controller;
    Animation<double> _animation;

    @override
    initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this, value: 0);
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);

    _controller.forward();
     }

    @override
    dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _animation,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Test',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just put this widget in the body of Scaffold in your home page.

Comment: In my code i have void main() => runApp(MaterialApp( home: Rehman() )); class Rehman extends StatefulWidget { override _RehmanState createState() => _RehmanState(); } class _RehmanState extends State<Rehman> { override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( ); so should i enter the class in scaffold?      @Benyamin

Comment: it will be like this : return Scaffold( body: _ScaleTransitionState() )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the widget like this

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Material(
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: _animation,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Test',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: In my code i have  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Rehman()
));

class Rehman extends StatefulWidget {
  override
  _RehmanState createState() => _RehmanState();
}

class _RehmanState extends State<Rehman> {

  override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      );                                                            so should i enter the class in scaffold?